# Need a working loadmask to Ext JS plugin Ext.ux.SimpleIFrame

Tags: extjs

I need a help with code below:

```
var panel = Ext.widget('panel', {
    title: 'Timesheet',
    height: 400,
    items: {
        xtype: 'component',
        //height: 400,
        autoEl: {
            tag: 'iframe',
            style: 'height: 100%; width: 100%; border: none;',
            src: 'index.html'
        },
        listeners: {
            load: {
                element: 'el',
                fn: function () {
                    //this.up('panel').body.unmask();
                    alert('Done!');
                }
            },
            render: function () {
                this.up('panel').body.mask('Loading...');
            }
        }
    }
 });
```

Loadmask appear but unmask function do not work (it gives a type error in Firebug). Load event works because alert prompts "Done!".

How to fix this code?

I am use Ext JS 4.2.+

Comment: Can you share some demo fiddle ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: He means this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor. It seems that the component you are referring to doesn't have a load event, does it?

Comment: Yes, component has no load event..

Comment: I can't get fiddle to work just now..

Comment: Why ? You just need to embed your code over there !!

Comment: Ok. I embed the code but no button to execute the code appeared.

Comment: Whitc one I embed the code? index.html or app.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work with code below:

```
var panel = Ext.widget('panel', {
    id: 'timesheet-panel',
    title: 'Timesheet',
    height: 400,
    items: {
        xtype: 'component',
        //height: 400,
        autoEl: {
            tag: 'iframe',
            style: 'height: 100%; width: 100%; border: none;',
            src: 'index.html'
        },
        listeners: {
            load: {
                element: 'el',
                fn: function () {
                    Ext.getCmp('timesheet-panel').body.unmask();
                    //alert('Done!');
                }
            },
            render: function () {
                Ext.getCmp('timesheet-panel').body.mask('Loading...');
            }
        }
    }
 });
```